# Change windows form application into MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an application which is built in windows form C# where I have a View, a Model and s ManagerHelper folder with classes in it. I wanted to convert this application into MVC application.

I know it's not convertable and needs to be implemented from scratch. The reason I wish to create to an MVC project is because I'm new to MVC and wish to learn it.

I'm familiar with HTML syntax however this seems to be really hard to get a grip of.

So my question is: What would a good approach if I which to change my windows form application into an MVC application.

Any link to articles or any books recommendation for Learning MVC would be helpful as well.

Comment: This is one of those scenarios why people emphasize N-tier design and separation of concerns so much. I don't know how your web forms app is structured and organized but if most of your logic is written inside your control's events you might as well start from scratch. However if your app is written well with clear separation of concerns and separate repository/business logic projects then, in theory, you would only need to recreate the presentation layer.

Comment: My form is well structured with all the business logic in the model folder. I don't have controller.

Answer (score 2):

There was an article about this in MSDN magazine last year. It should help guide you. You can read it [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991978.aspx)